# Gitlab Environments equivalent in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, cicd

Gitlab allows me to create different environments for a project (for example staging, uat & prod). This is very helpful since I can use same variable's name (eg: AWS_SECRET_KEY) in my pipeline script for difference environments.
I'm quited new to Jenkins, so far find it pretty cool due it its customization via plugins. But when it comes to deployment environment, I cannot find any plugins/ways to implement the same as in Gitlab. It's like if I want to deploy to staging, uat & prod, I need to create 3 variables with diff names, eg. STAGING_AWS_SECRET_KEY, UAT_AWS_SECRET_KEY, PROD_AWS_SECRET_KEY and my pipelines's scripts need to adjust accordingly to the env variables.
I just wonder how people deal with the environment in Jenkins?
**Editted**: I was wondering that did Jenkins have a feature that similar to Gitlab's Environments, but the answer is NO (according to @ AlexanderPletnev's answer).

I've been trying to find plugins that support that behavior for days, but found no viable solutions.

Comment: Why would you want to use Jenkins if you already have the whole GitLab available? Customization and plugins are its architecture legacy, not a cool feature...

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev Well gitlab CI/CD is an awesome platform, but difference projects dont allow me to only stick with it.

Comment: I don't think that Jenkins can do something that Gitlab can't, could you bring an example? In my understanding, it would make sense to build the deployment pipelines on Jenkins only if the project is already using Jenkins. But even if it's the case, chances are that it's better to migrate to Gitlab completely if you plan to use it further.

Comment: Well, the case is we have to use Jenkins as a deployment coordinator since everything in my system are set up with Jenkins. Yes, I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: if you're already using GitLab, I highly recommend using its own CI/CD functionality instead of building parallel solutions with Jenkins.

Now, to your question.

There are at least two options depending on the pipeline architecture you want to use. Also, it's usually simpler to use one variable name that has different values.

First, you can use different stages for different environments. This will allow you to make some deployments conditional, perform different operations before or after deployment depending on the target environment, and is generally useful in build pipelines that trigger the deployments automatically or if you want to have a single pipeline for the whole CI/CD process of an application:

```java
// Jenkinsfile

pipeline {
  // ...
  stages {
    stage('Deploy to staging') {
      environment {
        AWS_SECRET_KEY = credentials('aws-key-staging')
      }
      steps {
        // Use AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variable here
      }
    }
    
    stage('Deploy to UAT') {
      environment {
        AWS_SECRET_KEY = credentials('aws-key-uat')
      }
      steps {
        // Steps could be different if you want
        // You can use the same AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variable here
      }
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can parametrize the secret name. This could be useful for the deployment pipelines that are used separately, when you have a significant number of the environments and/or want to control the deployments manually. Note the usage of double quotes for the secret name:

```java
// Jenkinsfile

pipeline {
  // ...
  parameters {
    choice name: 'Target environment',
           description: 'Some description',
           choices: [
             'staging',
             'uat',
             'prod'
           ]   
  }
  stages {
    stage('Deployment') {
      environment {
        AWS_SECRET_KEY = credentials("aws-key-${params.'Target environment'}")
      }
      steps {
        // Use AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variable here
      }
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

You can also combine these two approaches and set the target environment name in the previous stages.

Comment: I got what you meant. Maybe my question was not so clear but what I was questioning is, does Jenkins have a feature similar to Gitlab's Environments, which allows us to define several variables with the same name for each targeted env (so that we dont need to parameterized the secret name like what u recommend)? @AlexanderPletnev

Comment: No, there is no concept of environments in Jenkins. The closest thing to what you're referring to is my first example. You can also create a separate job per each environment but the overall approach will remain.

Comment: If you make separate jobs, you'll get separate deployment history for each environment. In order to keep the pipeline code the same, you'll still need to parametrize the secret name and [define the pipeline code in a shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines).

Comment: Ooh I should have asked a question kinda "does Jenkins have a similar concept of environment?" from the begining. Thank you for the super detailed answer. Really want to give ur answer an upvote, but my acc is under-reputation and cannot make it now :(.